# Can "through" be after "be"?

Tags: word-usage

I know "walk through", "pass through", "go through", ...
I find a sentence

> The restaurant was through a low arch

What is the property of "through" here (verb, adv)?

Comment: Try preposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Through* is a preposition.

Prepositional phrases can follow *be*.

*To be* can be used to express the location of something and prepositional phrases are often needed for that.

*Through* also means "completed" and using *to be* to say something is completed is fine and expected.

> I am through working today.

Comment: You can also use it for location, like _go_ or _walk_. _I was through that mall the other day and the parking lot is all torn up._